# INSERT INTO SELECT in Slick that runs on the server. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I’m going to duplicate some records in table tbl.

It looks like

```
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT id+100, name FROM tbl
```

in plain SQL.

I expected that it could look like

```
db.run(
         tableQuery.forceInsertQuery(
           tableQuery.map{rec=>rec.copy(id=rec.id+100)}
))
```

in Slick, where
`rec` is an instance of `Table[ScalaCaseClassForTbl]`
with

```
   val id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
   val name = column[String]("name")
```

and

```
override def * : ProvenShape[ScalaCaseClassForTbl] =
```

But I do not understand how to make `map`.

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with...

```scala
tableQuery.map{rec=>rec.copy(id=rec.id+100)}
```

...is that `rec` is not a case class, so there's not a `copy`.

What you can do is `map` to a tuple of the columns (the `Rep[T]`) values) and then convert that to a case class.

For example:

```scala
tableQuery.map{ rec =>
 (rec.id+100, rec.name).mapTo[YourCaseClass]
}
```